# Run time error in spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

thank you for your time. I've put stars on the error line if this helps.

I'm lost with an error and I can't find the reason. Can I get some help, please? The macros is not running for only one period and I didn't find any different data in the database compare to the previous period

That's the debug menu:

Get values and convert to string for text box:

```
a = Format(.Cells(rowNum, dateCol), "dd mmm")
a = a + ", " + Str(.Cells(rowNum, actualAssetCol))
```

Get values and convert to string for text box:

```
a = Format(.Cells(rowNum, dateCol), "dd mmm")
a = a + ", " + Str(.Cells(rowNum, actualAssetCol))`
```

Comment: Try to simplify your code so it only contains the issue at hand.
Also please provide us with the exact error message and on which line it occurs in the debugger.

Comment: 'get values and convert to string for text box
        a = Format(.Cells(rowNum, dateCol), "dd mmm")
        a = a + ", " + Str(.Cells(rowNum, actualAssetCol))**********

Comment: OK, it looks like you are constructing a text date from the month and day from one cell as well as the year from another. Can you hover over *a* to see what it currently is? Have you looked at the Locals window to see what the values of the variables are?

Answer (score 1):

The string concatenation operator in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) is `&` and not `+`. Thus, use it like this:

```
a = a & ", " & Str(.Cells(rowNum, actualAssetCol))`
```

Comment: It's true, and the OP runs the risk of adding the numbers rather than concatenating them but it does work in this instance.